# What should a wife do if her husband stops praying?

Tags: salat, husband-wife

If a husband has stopped praying, what should his wife do concerning this issue?

Especially that he is not planning to pray anymore.

Comment: What should is the begining of an advise request and attracting opinion-based answers. From the perspective of Islam she should let him know that this would take him out if the folds of Islam, which will make her unlawful for him and she can go to court to ask for faskh (invalidation) of the marriage! You should also explain what is the reason for the husband to stop praying?

Comment: You are supposed to try a little more before invalidating a wedding. Do you know why he stopped praying ? There are plenty of different reasons, from hurting back or knees to disagreements with the people in charge of the local mosque. It would help to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: @user5751924 What Medi1Saif said is that if you abandon prayer, that makes you a kafir, and a marriage between a kafir and a Muslim(ah) is invalid.

Comment: The question is unclear. Does the husband not pray because of laziness or is it because he has apostatized and thinks that he does not need to pray?